# Rendering array into tabular form

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

In this code I am trying to render the csv data into tabular form after doing some processing on it. The result I am getting is in form:

[image]

whereas, I need to get the result like this:

[image]

I tried with ._zip_underscore and it is giving me an exception with underscore.js file. I am not sure how to do that. Please help. Code is below.

**JavaScript**

```
function execData(file) 
{
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file);
    reader.onload = function (event)
    {
        var csv = event.target.result;
        var data = $.csv.toArrays(csv);
        var data1 = data;
        var header = data1.shift();
        var numeric = 0;
        var str = 0;
        var dtr = new Array();


        for (var i = 0; i < data1[i].length; i ++ )
        {
            // alert("backa");
            for (var m = 0; m < data1[m].length; m ++ )
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < data1.length; j ++ )
                {
                   var r = data1[j][i];
                   dt(r);

                }
            dttop(m);


            }
        }

        function dt(x)
        {
            //  alert("here");
            if (isFinite(x) == true)
            {
                numeric ++ ;

            }

            else
            {
                str ++ ;

            }
        }

        function dttop(f)
        {

            if (numeric > str)
            dtr[f] = "n";
            else
            dtr[f] = "s";
        }



        //  alert(dtr);
        var final = dtr.concat(data1);

        // to render in a tabular format
        var html = '';

        for (var row in final)
        {
            html += '<tr>\n';

            for (var item in final[row])
            {
                html += '<td>' + final[row][item] + '</td>\n';
            }
            // alert(html);
            html += '</tr>\n';
        }

        $('#contents').html(html);
    };
    reader.onerror = function ()
    {
        alert('Unable to read ' + file.fileName);

    };
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id=inputs class=clearfix>
    <input type=file id=files name=files[] multiple />
</div>
<hr />

<output id=list></output>
<hr />

<table id=contents style="width:100%; height:400px;"></table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand...

The structure of the data is printed as `final[row][item]`, but the three first rows in `dtr` contain only one value each.

Place an array in the first position of `dtr`.

```
dtr[0] = new Array();
```

Your function should be now something more like:

```
function dttop(f)
{
    if (numeric > str)
        dtr[0][f] = "n";
    else
        dtr[0][f] = "s";
}
```

Comment: is that a right 'dtr[0] = new Array();' as it is giving me a critical error says 'Expected ';''

Comment: Which line? The one that gave you the error? I didn't get that error myself so check if it's just a typo.